# What is this technological device?

Tags: identification, device

Today at work, I came across [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DO5sRr1SNM0T2KNyVWKY-pOgCBFgVSiJ?usp=sharing) device. One of the black lids has the inscription **PGEP79**. A small amount of colorless liquid was contained inside the transparent casing. Overall, it looks like an electrical device, so that's why I decided to ask the question here. If this community does not tolerate such questions, kindly direct me to an appropriate forum. Thank you.

Example photo:

[image]

Comment: I once took apart a discarded vaping device. It had an air flow switch inside it that looked a lot like your images.

Comment: why dont you ask at work?

Comment: @DaveTweed, could you please share photos, if any? Alternatively, do you remember which specific vaping device it was?

Comment: @jsotola problem is, I don't know whose it is, and asking all of my colleagues just isn't feasible.

Comment: take it to a vape shop and ask there

Comment: I wonder why would you care about the specific vape model while you are given some random used cartridge.

Comment: @EugeneSh. had you provided a specific vaping model, I would have sourced for its manual, which would have led me to a catalogue of its parts, which would have led me to its cartridge which would have increased my confidence in what I have being a cartridge from a vaping device. But what do I know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a used cartridge from a vaping device. There is an electrical heater inside that vaporizes the liquid so the user can inhale it.

You should be able to measure the heater resistance if you have a multimeter- it should be around a couple ohms or less (down to less than 0.5\$\Omega\$).

Comment: Could you share any similar images?

Comment: Google vaping cartridge. I found one outside, examined it and discarded it, but didn't bother with photos.